# Put a custom http header in backbone

Tags: http, backbone.js, tastypie

I am creating an API with Tastypie and I want to access to the API from Backbone. 
To send credentials I use an user_id and a api_key. I do this in android and with curl and this work great, but I can set the http header from backbone.

In curl I use:

```
 curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "user_id: 32" -H "api_key: 69950" -X DELETE "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/deletenote/66/?format=json"
```

and in android java I use:

```
    HttpDelete requestDELETE = new HttpDelete();
    requestDELETE.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    requestDELETE.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    requestDELETE.setHeader(Constants.HEADER_USER_ID, user_id);
    requestDELETE.addHeader(Constants.HEADER_API_KEY, key);
```

Both of them work great, but when I try this in Backbone following the responses that I found in other post from the page, this didn't work.

I am trying this:

```
var removeNote = new DeleteNoteModel({id:this.model.toJSON().id},{ query:this.model.toJSON().id});


removeNote.destroy({ 
        headers: {'user_id':dataWeb.get("id"),'api_key':dataWeb.get("api_key")}
        },{
                    async:false,
                    error: function(model, response){
                        console.log("KO_REMOVE_NOTE");
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                     success : function(model, response){
                        console.log("OK_REMOVE_NOTE");
                        console.log(response);
                     }
                }
    );
```

I'm putting the header when I call to the destroy call, but this don't send anithing to the server.

What I am doing in a wrong mode?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tallmaris answer should fix it for you though I would recommend usign jQuery [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method to setup the headers as default values for all ajax requests as I believe you need them all the time anyway right?

Somewhere where you launch the App put in

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'user_id':dataWeb.get("id"),
        'api_key':dataWeb.get("api_key")
    }
});
```

Thanks to that you'll save yourself a lot of repeated code :) keep it DRY!

(obviously you'd need to ensure that dataWeb is available in the scope of where you launch the app :) )

Comment: Thanks!!! It's work! I finally can remove a note! The ajax parameters put the header correctly. Putting the header in the backbone method doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can't seem to get my headers to be respected, or sent to the server.  Where should I set this?

Comment: This uses jQuery ajaxSetup to globally alter all the requests made using jquery (Backbone uses them internally) best place to put it would be somewhere where you setup and run your app.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are passing two parameters to destroy, pass only one containing the headers and the other options together, unless the brackets order is a typo. Try this:

```
removeNote.destroy({ 
    headers: {
        'user_id':dataWeb.get("id"),
        'api_key':dataWeb.get("api_key")
    }, // there was an extra close-open curly here...
    async:false,
    error: function(model, response){
        console.log("KO_REMOVE_NOTE");
        console.log(response);
    },
    success : function(model, response){
        console.log("OK_REMOVE_NOTE");
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Using an Ajax parameters work fine for me. I try this but this isn't the problem. Thanks for the answer.